# sap.ui.table.Table with CheckBox as one of the Columns

Tags: sapui5

I'm wondering if there are gists or JSBins, with the functionality of `sap.ui.table.Table` having CheckBoxes in them. And upon selecting the required Checkboxes and submitting for batch update/add of selected/checked rows to OData $batch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've figured it out that the core examples of table has check boxes in sapui5 demokit.